# Insert superscript letters into VARCHAR2 column specifically trademark symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert a superscript symbol, trademark into a VARCHAR2 column in Oracle SQL developer. I do not want to use NVARCHAR, which works.

I have tried using NVARCHAR as the type and it works but I can only use VARCHAR2.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 
   (    "DESCRIPTION_EN" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)
   );

insert into test1 (  DESCRIPTION_EN) values ('Hello World ' || unistr('\2122') );

SELECT * FROM test1;
```

The trademark symbol as a superscript is the result I am looking for (™), yet I am seeing inverted question mark.

Comment: What do you get when you run `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';`?

Comment: WE8ISO8859P15 and encoding is CP1252

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.

`WE8ISO8859P15` is the Oracle identifier for [ISO-8859-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15#Codepage_layout). That encoding that does not have the ™ symbol (aka U+2122 'TRADE MARK SIGN').

That's precisely the issue that `NVARCHAR` came to solve ;-)

---

Interestingly, you mention [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#cite_ref-bestfit_5-0) and that encoding supports the symbol, but that isn't your *database* encoding.

Comment: You can use the characters shown in the codepage layout table I've linked. For anything else there's Unicode. (I know the TM symbol but I've never heard about the T or M symbols you suggest...)

Comment: if you don't want to use NVARCHAR2 (why not?), then convert your database character set to UTF8 or to what you require